# BehaviorSubject/Subject Emits Values for Primitive and References for Non-Primitive - POC Results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can somebody put some light on below, as it is not widely discussed topic over the internet. Will be helpful, if someone confirms it with further analysis.

I wonder to see that **Subject and BS emits only references for non-Primitive data types** within the subscription. So if multiple components are using an emitted object, those are accessing only single copy which is shared across components.

These are observations from my POC : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-starter-project-daidh-4x2jth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstudent.service.ts

For quick look sharing the code screen shots below :

student.service.ts :

```
  studentSubject = new Subject<any>();
  counterSubject = new Subject<any>();
  emitValues() {
    //get student obj from db here
    let student = { rollNo: 1, name: 'student1', age: 20 };
    this.studentSubject.next(student);

    let counter = 1;
    this.counterSubject.next(counter);
  }
```

Above 2 subjects are subscribed in 3 components and the emitted values are bound with the textbox values.

**For Student object (non-Primitive) :** changes from any component to the emitted value, will reflect in the other components, though the object is not actually shared object through the service.

**For Counter value (Primitive) :** changes from any component to the emitted value, will not reflect to other components.

student1.component.ts:

```
  student: any = {};
  counter: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this._studentService.studentSubject.subscribe((stud) => {
      this.student = stud;
      console.log(stud);
    });
    this._studentService.counterSubject.subscribe((counter) => {
      this.counter = counter;
    });
  }
```

student2.component.ts:

```
  student: any = {};
  counter: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this._studentService.studentSubject.subscribe((stud) => {
      this.student = stud;
      console.log(stud);
    });
    this._studentService.counterSubject.subscribe((counter) => {
      this.counter = counter;
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is nothing related to rxjs. In JavaScript objects are always passed by copy-reference